# SSMS 2014 reporting service configuration ,Reporting Services – SharePoint integrated mode option is not working

Tags: ssms

I uninstalled SSMS 2014 due to some reason and when i went reinstalling it i am facing an issue that Reporting Services – SharePoint is not highlighted in feature selection and Reporting Services – SharePoint integrated mode is not working in reporting service configuration.
Please help me setting this up.